# How to specify input function parameter type and return type when passing the function as an argument to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have some set of functionlike below:

```
def bar(b: str, func)->int:
    return func(b)
```

I would like to specify in `bar` the input type and return type of `func` that get's passed as a parameter. That way I can pass in a different versions of `func` that also take a string but return an int.

Something maybe like

```
def bar(b: str, func(a: str) -> list)->int:
    my_list = func(b)
    my_output = # do something with my_list that returns an int
    return my_output
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is this possible in python?

Comment: *return type of func* - but you're returning the result of that function

Comment: Hey, so I updated the question with something a little more clarifying. I don't intend that `func` has the same return type as `bar` it just happened to be that way when I wrote the example.

Comment: You should re-edit: if `func(a: str) -> list` then *bar* can't return a `int`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

```
from typing import Callable

def bar(b: str, func: Callable[[str], int])->int:
    return func(b)
```